# Превратить список из списков в стрим (на Java)

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть клиент. У клиента есть несколько счетов. А к каждому счёту привязано несколько карт. Чтобы получить список всех карт клиента я делаю так:

```
        List<Card> allCards = new ArrayList<>();        
        List<Account> accounts = client.getAccounts();
        for (Account a : accounts) {
            List<Card> cards = a.getCards();
            allCards.addAll(cards);
        }
        log.debug("Все карты клиента: " + allCards);
```

А можно это сделать как-то через стрим? Наподобие такого:

```
         List<Card> allCards2 = client.getAccounts()
                .stream()
                .map(account -> account.getCards().stream())
                .reduce() // тут ошибка, красным подсвечивает
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` и `collect` являются [терминальными операциями](https://devmark.ru/article/stream-api-terminal-opers) в стриме и поэтому не могут применяться одновременно.

Для решения данной задачи проще всего в исходном коде заменить `.map` на [`.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) и убрать `reduce`, оставив `collect`:

```java
List<Card> allCards2 = client.getAccounts()
        .stream() // Stream<Account>
        .flatMap(account -> account.getCards().stream()) // Stream<Card>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Или же можно использовать `map` для преобразования стрима счетов в стрим списков карт, к которому уже применить [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) для получения общего списка карт.  Основной недостаток такого решения в том, что стандартный метод `List::addAll` возвращает `boolean` и потому ссылка на этот метод не может быть непосредственно использована в качестве `BinaryOperator<List<Card>>`, потребуется написать отдельную лямбду/функцию:

```java
List<Card> allCards3 = client.getAccounts()
        .stream() // Stream<Account>
        .map(Account::getCards) // Stream<List<Card>>
        .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (acc, cards) -> { 
            acc.addAll(cards);
            return acc;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте flatMap

Как пример, допустим есть класс

```
static class Account
{
    public List<String> GetCards(){
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        ret.add("one");
        ret.add("two");
        ret.add("three");
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Накидаем список с данными

```
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
accounts.add(new Account());
accounts.add(new Account());
accounts.add(new Account());
accounts.add(new Account());
```

И обработаем карты

```
accounts.stream()
        .map(account->account.GetCards())
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод

```
one
two
three
one
two
three
one
two
three
one
two
three
```